# Can MessageBox.Show cause cross-thread exceptions?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Can I call `MessageBox.Show` on a child thread without worrying about a cross-thread exception?  I know the ostensible answer would be "try it and find out", which I did, successfully, but I've noticed that Windows 7 seems to be less strict about raising cross-thread exceptions than Windows XP.

So, is it documented anywhere that this would be safe to do from a child thread?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What would be the source of the cross-thread exception?

Comment: AFAIK *cross-thread invocation* exceptions are not OS-dependent. They're the documented result of using the WinForms API in a certain manner.

Comment: @Jon, I just want to make certain that calling MessageBox.Show does not constitute UI access in the same way that messing with a combo box would be.  I assume not, but I wanted to be sure

Comment: @Martino, I've (stupidly) written bad code that accessed UI elements from a child thread that worked fine, and didn't get sent back to me until someone tested it on Windows XP.  I don't know why Win7 is so lenient about this, but it is :(

Comment: That's not possible, this is pure .NET plumbing that doesn't have anything to do with the operating system.  The exception will never be raised without a debugger.

Comment: @Hans, see Alex's answer on this question.  I don't claim to be an expert on .NET plumbing, but the situation I described most certainly did happen  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018169/are-cross-thread-exceptions-less-strict-in-windows-7

Comment: Odd that you accepted the answer to that question.  It says nothing at all about Win7.  Never mess with CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls.

Comment: He said the result of that operation is undefined, which was the behavior I was seeing.  I was just trying to understand why some code was throwing the cross-thread ex on one OS, and not another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it will not cause any "cross-thread" exceptions. That's because the MessageBox is not a member of a class running on the UI thread.

Answer (score 9):

If you call `MessageBox.Show("text")` without an owner window you are save.
If you call `MessageBox.Show` like `MessageBox.Show(this,"text")` specifying the owner window things are different.

I have seen that in Windows XP you are save but in Windows 7 you will run into a cross-thread exception if the owner window is running in a different thread than the thread from which you call the `MessageBox`!

Comment: I'm seeing this now :( I have a messagebox which shows behind the form. If I add the owner as you have stated, then I get a "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '[my form]' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

Answer (score 1):

You are safe to throw a MessageBox in a separate thread. But keep in mind that it will only block the thread that it was created on. If you are using a WinForm app and another thread calls the MessageBox then the form is still able to be played around with and the user can ignore it.