# MessageBox.Show Causing Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, show, messagebox

In my application, I have the code below for saving an excel file:

```
...
try {
  workbook.SaveAs(filename, ".xls");
}
catch (IOException ex) {
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error saving file", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
}
...
```

If the file specified by "filename" is in use, an IOException occurs which is the normal behavior. However, it has happened to a couple of our customers, that the call to MessageBox.Show throws an exception:

---

### Stack trace

```
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl(): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke(): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue(): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(HandleRef hWnd, String text, String caption, Int32 type): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.MessageBox.ShowCore(IntPtr owner, String messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon, MessageBoxResult defaultResult, MessageBoxOptions options): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
at System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(String messageBoxText, String caption, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage icon): 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would really appreciate if anybody can offer any insight on this. Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Comment: Your catch block looks fine to me. Have you actually tried setting a breakpoint and inspect the behavior?

Comment: I have, and everything works fine in my environment. I'm not able to reproduce the exception at all. But we have received multiple error reports from customers and looking at the stack trace, they all look like the one I posted. Thanks.

Comment: The error on top of the stack trace is a `List` to `Array` implicit conversion exception, which is not what is happening at all in your catch block.

Comment: I agree. But the call at the bottom of the stack trace is indeed the call inside the catch block. I'm guessing something is going wrong in one of the internal calls, but I have no idea on how to figure out what it is or why.

Comment: It looks to me like there's a Threading issue. Are you running this in a background thread? If so, you should probably try running the MessageBox to the UI Dispatcher: Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox...);

Comment: Is the message the same as in the example, or are there variables in there? The error message indicate that there is a problem in one of values in the Arguments. If not, there may be a problem with ex.Message not being able to convert to string, which is strange...

Comment: @NateDiamond, the code is indeed running in a background thread. I thought that the calls to MessageBox.Show were thread safe, are they not? Thanks.

Comment: @GerhardPowell, by inspecting the error report I can see that the exception message is a string, so that shouldn't be the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @user2370685 According to the doc, "Message boxes always have an owner window. By default, the owner of a message box is the window that is currently active in an application at the time that a message box is opened. However, you can specify another owner for the Window by using one of several Show overloads. For more information about owner windows, see Window.Owner."

Comment: @user2370685 Further, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421531/can-messagebox-show-cause-cross-thread-exceptions), the message box is dispatched on the thread of the window, in this case the default one. I *think* this means that it's *possible* for it to be marshalled to a different thread, though I'd have to know more about the implementation than I do. At least, this will give you a plan of attack for repro-ing and possibly fixing.

Comment: @NateDiamond Thank you very much for your help. I will try moving the call to the UI thread to see if it fixes the issue.