# Does Parallel.ForEach() perform only one action?

Tags: c#

I'm having difficulty sending emails using parallel for each ... in case, the code works perfectly, however it does not send all emails. It is effectively sending only 1 ... no error and sent by the compiler.

```
MailSender emailHelper = new MailSender(server, serverPort, loginName, password, true);

Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(textBoxListaClientes.Text), 
                 new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, 
                 line =>
{
      //NOME CLIENTE;EMAIL
      string[] linhaQuebrada = line.Split(';');

      emailHelper.Send(loginName, linhaQuebrada[1], assunto, message);

      MessageBox.Show("Email send to => " + linhaQuebrada[0]);

});

MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

My file =>

```
Name1;email1@example.com
Name2;email2@example.com
Name3;email3@example.com
Name4;email4@example.com
```

I'm not able to identify what I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: can paste output of this File.ReadLines(textBoxListaClientes.Text) ..or debug and check it giving you multiple line s

Comment: I did this, it's playing inside the foreach only 1 line and ending the execution ... how can I fix it?

Comment: check for the exception ...

Comment: Does your code work OK as a normal (non-parallel) `for each` ?

Comment: Will `MessageBox.Show` work from those other threads?

Comment: @PranayRana they are catching all lines now, but not sending to all... just one... when i use breakpoint they send to all...

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - it should work i checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421531/can-messagebox-show-cause-cross-thread-exceptions

Comment: can you just comment code of email and message box , and just write on console using console.writeline ..then see it working or not

Comment: @PranayRana they are writing all lines on console

Comment: Check my answer I given code and its working fine in my console application....

Comment: @NarimGobb You cannot use `MessageBox` from a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are running your own SMTP server, there is no reason to use Parallel.ForEach().  Because other email provider will limit your number of connection.  They will think you are trying to send SPAM.

Try to send one email.

If that email works, then remove the Parallel.ForEach() and use a delay for about 5 seconds in between each message.  Sending a hundred (100) message should only take a little more than 8 minutes.

Your second choice is to use a [Email marketing software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Email_marketing_software).

Comment: I was able to use another way to make it work, however, actually SMTP blocks. Thanks